# Add external exe file in my setup file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, exe, setup-deployment

I have created a WPF app on Visual Studio 2015. I have created installer using WIX toolset. Now I need to add an external exe file into setup.

Please, let me know the way, How to add exe file into my installer package.

Comment: You can add that exe in your solution and set its `Build Action: Content` and `Copy to output Directory: Copy always`. The installer should automatically include the file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do I need to Drag and Drop exe file into solution explorer, or Need to setup new project for exe in same solution?

Comment: You can add file by right-clicking on the project or drag-n-drop works (may need to include in the project).

Comment: It is just placing exe file in the same folder in Programming files, not installing that one?